# Why "which cp | ls -l " is not treate as "ls -l $(which cp)"?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, pipe, ls

According to pipe methodology in Linux, the output of the first command should be treated as input for the second command. So when I am doing `which cp | ls -l`, it should be treated as `ls -l $(which cp)`

But the output is showing something else.

Why so ?

Comment: What does it show when you run it ? Also consider the fact WHICH may not return a value.

Comment: It list the information about the files/directory in current directory. Its show same output as "ls -l".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ls` does not take input from `stdin`.  You can work around this if you need to by using `xargs`:

```
which cp | xargs ls -l
```

This will invoke `ls -l` with the (possibly multiple, if `which` were to return more than one) filenames as command line arguments, with no standard input.